# How to compare elements of an array in scala (using tail recursive)

Tags: scala

I'm trying to solve the following problem and cannot find any solutions, could you please help with this:

> Implement a higher order function that checks if an `Array[A]` is sorted given a comparison function as an argument:
>
> ```scala
> def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], comparison: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean
> ```
>
> Ensure that your implementation is tail recursive, and use an appropriate annotation.
>
> 1. Example1:
>
>    ```scala
>    isSorted[Int](Array(1, 2, 3), (x, y) => x <= y)
>    ```
>
>    should be `true`
> 2. Example2:
>
>    ```scala
>    isSorted[Int](Array(2, 2, 2), (x, y) => x == y)
>    ```
>
>    should be `true`
> 3. Example3:
>
>    ```scala
>    isSorted[Int](Array(2, 2, 2), (x, y) => x < y)
>    ```
>
>    should be `false`

```scala
def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], comparison: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def iterator(as: Array[A], a: Int, b: Int): Boolean =
    if (as.size == 0 || as.size == 1)
      true
    else if (b + 1 < as.size)
      if (comparison(as(a), as(b)))
        iterator(as, b, b + 1) 
      else
        false
    else
      true

  iterator(as, 0, 1)
}
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: hi, edited the post @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: It would appear that whatever comparison function you're passing in to test your implementation is returning an `Int` rather than a `Boolean`.

Comment: Your compile error points to the code line `return n`, which is probably returns `Int` but there is an expected `Boolean` value, but in your code snippet there is no `return n` code, please, provide an actual code example.

Comment: May I ask where you got this task? It does not specify what the `comparison` function does, it uses strange code formatting, and it uses a single argument list where the type inference would require two separate argument lists. That's three red flags in five lines, looks a bit unexpected, tbh.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: Four red flags. Nobody uses `Array`s in Scala, and certainly nobody should teach them.

Comment: What is your question? The code you posted works just fine. The error message you posted *cannot possibly* come from the code you posted, since the line in the error message does not appear anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. How would you solve it without the extra constraints? You would have to check that

- For all indices `i` in the range `0` until `arr.size - 1`
- the condition `comparison(arr(i), arr(i + 1))` holds.

That is:

```
def isSorted[A](arr: Array[A])(cmp: (A, A) => Boolean) =
  (0 until (arr.size - 1)).forall(i => cmp(arr(i), arr(i + 1)))
```

---

2. Now, where's the iteration/recursion hidden? It's inside of the `forall`
   method for the range. So, reimplement the `forall` on your own,
   obeying the constraints of the task:

```
def rangeForall(r: Range, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def rec(idx: Int): Boolean = 
    if (idx >= r.end) {
      true
    } else if (p(idx)) {
      rec(idx + 1)
    } else {
      false
    }
  rec(r.start)
}
```

Note how it can be tested separately, and that it requires neither nested functions nor generics or anything like that.

Use that instead of the built-in `forall`:

```
def isSorted[A](as: Array[A])(cmp: (A, A) => Boolean) =
  rangeForall(0 until (as.size - 1), i => cmp(as(i), as(i + 1)))
```

Sanity check:

```
println(isSorted(Array(1, 2, 3))(_ <= _)) // true
println(isSorted(Array(2, 2, 2))(_ == _)) // true
println(isSorted(Array(2, 2, 2))(_ < _)) // false
```

---

Note that the function signature has *two* argument lists: this is necessary so that the type parameter is inferred from the array only, before the type checker gets to the second argument list. In this way, you don't have to write out the `[Int]` every time.

Comment: Would you be interested in offering some functional scala tutoring? (I failed a uni exam on it, and look for some help) - any answer is very much appreciated, thx

Comment: @tester Let's move the unrelated discussions [to a chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242682/room-for-andrey-tyukin-and-tester).

Answer (score 1):

Short and sweet.

```
@annotation.tailrec
def isSorted[A](as: Seq[A], comparison: (A,A)=>Boolean): Boolean = as match {
  case Seq() => true
  case Seq(_) => true
  case a+:b+:z => if (comparison(a,b)) isSorted(b+:z, comparison)
                  else false
}
```